# Deploy Django on Apache virtual host: 404

Tags: django, apache

I know there are a lot of articles talking about this issue, but I keep getting a 404 error when deploying a Django site through Apache virtual host. Here is my .conf file:

```
Listen 8001
<VirtualHost *:8001>
  ServerName www.myhostname.com/basic
  ServerAdmin caisj@example.com

  ProxyRequests Off
  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  DocumentRoot /home/browser/BASIC/basic

  Alias /static /home/browser/BASIC/basic/static
  Alias /media /home/browser/BASIC/_py/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.6.egg/django/contrib/admin/media

  WSGIScriptAlias /basic /home/browser/BASIC/basic/basic.wsgi
  ErrorLog /home/browser/BASIC/basic/log/basic.error.log

  LogLevel info
  CustomLog /home/browser/BASIC/basic/log/basic.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I have tried different combinations of the "ServerName" and other parameters, but when visiting www.myhostname.com/basic, I keep getting a 404 error. The Apache restarts successfully and the log file contains no clues.

Or could anybody help to tell where to find errors? Thanks.

Comment: You accessed the server with 8001 port?

Comment: What URL are you requesting? You've configured the Django app to serve at `/basic`, so that's what you need to access.

Comment: @daniel-roseman, I tried both www.myhostname.com/basic and www.myhostname.com:8001, but both failed...

Comment: Because you need both: www.myhostname.com:8001/basic

Comment: @daniel-roseman. Er... Yes, you are right. Thanks a lot. Please answer the question so that I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set this up to listen on port 8001 and rooted at `/basic`, so you need to access `www.myhostname.com:8001/basic`.

Note that you shouldn't set `DocumentRoot` to the location of your Django files. It isn't necessary to serve a Django app, and it could potentially be a security risk - a misconfiguration could mean that your code files, including any db passwords, might be served.